# Need to calculate the 3D volume of a growing 4D hypersphere in Minkowski space

Tags: spheres, noneuclidean-geometry, 4-manifolds

4D geometry and Minkowski space are areas of expertise which I fundamentally lack, so I'm hoping people are able to help me with this.

The problem is this, if you had a hypersphere in Minkowski space whose temporal radius was increasing at a rate of c how would you calculate the rate of expansion of the 3D portion of the volume?

Comment: If you have a 3D ball with points coordinatized $(x,y,t)$, can you calculate the area of the part that lies in the plane $t=0$?  What about the length of the corresponding line in a 2D ball?

Comment: Is it really that simple? Just extend the same reasoning into 4 dimensions?

Comment: Usually, yes.  Do you have a definition of spatial volume that you're using?  If so, you should edit it into the question.  If not, it's fair to assume that you're using the usual definition, for which the sort of reasoning I suggested applies.

Comment: (Worth mentioning: the difference between Minkowski space and standard $\mathbb{R}^4$ is in measuring lengths.  From a mathematician's perspective, this is introduced via a Riemannian metric, which gets defined long after coordinatal distance and volume get defined.)